# A word for obligatory but not relevant activities

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Suppose that your job is an academic, then you may need to:
1. perform the research,
2. apply for a research grant.

The tasks of the first kind contribute directly to your becoming a better researcher. The tasks of the second kind have to be performed otherwise you will not have funding to conduct the research, however, applying for a grant does not make you a better researcher, hence acts more like a distraction than as a relevant part of your research.

What are the names for the first and second kinds of activities?
I thought of words: 1. main, 2. support. However, these two words are only a bare extraction of the meaning to be expressed, moreover their meaning may be even misleading in the context I descri

Comment: 1. core activity, 2. paperwork

Comment: *Goal tasks & Enabling tasks*: 'otherwise you will not have funding to conduct the research,' makes the task 'apply for a research grant' contributory/ supportive to research, though in a secondary/ indirect way, it's not a 'goal task', but an 'enabling task'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would describe them as:

- [primary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/primary) roles; and
- [ancillary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ancillary) roles

Comment: I'd say *ancillary task* rather than role, with an *ancillary role* being e.g. that of office admin staff who don't do the primary business of an organisation, but are vital to it getting done. That said, definitely a +1 for *ancillary*.
Informally, some ancillary tasks get called *housekeeping*, but not all, and *ancillary* remains the formal word to use.

Answer (score 1):

Another word which may be of interest is 'perfunctory', meaning that you carry out a task without real interest, feeling or effort. Because a task is ancillary to your main one  doesn't necessarily mean you carry it out in a perfunctory manner. However the PO's mention of the second task being 'more like a distraction' did lead me to think that 'perfunctory' might be the word they were looking for in this case.